# Building a tracking spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been working on a tracking spreadsheet that will notify a staff member when a client is in need of a resolution and to calculate the number of days between when a resolution is needed and when the issue is resolved. Right now I am using:

=IF(I3-G3<0,"Needs Resolution",I3-G3)

What I also need is a way to make this same cell empty in the event that another cell (H3) is filled with a date.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy!

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H3), IF(I3-G3<0,"Needs Resolution",I3-G3), "")
```